# calculating curvilinear integral by residue theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus, complex-integration

> Calculate the following integral by transposing to a curve integral
>   and then using the residue theorem: $\displaystyle
>  \int_{0}^{2\pi}{\frac{e^{int}}{C-e^{it}}dt}, \qquad |C|\ne1, n\in
>  \mathbb N$.

My idea: 
I use the curve $\gamma:[0;2\pi]\to\mathbb{C}, \gamma(t)=e^{it}.$ 
Then:

$\displaystyle\int_{\gamma}\frac{z^{n-1}}{C-z}dz=\int_{0}^{2\pi}{\frac{(e^{it})^{n-1}}{C-e^{it}}\cdot ie^{it} dt}=i\cdot\int_{0}^{2\pi}{\frac{e^{itn}}{C-e^{it}}dt}$.

Let $\displaystyle f(z):=\frac{z^{n-1}}{C-z}$. $f$ has a single pole at $C$ (for $C\ne 0$) and if $C=0$ it has a removable singularity there.

And then by applying the residue theorem:

$\displaystyle\int_{\gamma}\frac{z^{n-1}}{C-z}dz=2\pi i \cdot Res_{C}(f)=-2\pi i C^{n-1}.$

So $\displaystyle \int_{0}^{2\pi}{\frac{e^{itn}}{C-e^{it}}dt}=-2\pi C^{n-1}.$

But if I compare results to the results calculated by wolfram alpha they differ, so I assume my solution is wrong.

Comment: it depends if $|C| < 1$. assuming it is, up to a minus sign it seems correct

Comment: And what's with |C|>1? Besides I don't find the mistake regarding the minus sign.

Comment: When $|C|>1$ then $\gamma$ is nullhomotopic in $\mathbb{C}\backslash {C}$. Since f is holomorphic in $\mathbb{C}\backslash {C}$, the curvilinear integral is $0$ then. Right?

Comment: yes, the result is $-2 \pi C^{n-1} 1_{|C| < 1}$ for $|C| \ne 1$. for $|C| = 1$ it is undefined, except if you use the Cauchy principal value, then it is $- \pi C^{n-1}$ (the mean value of $\int_{|z| = 1-\epsilon}$ and $\int_{|z| = 1+\epsilon}$ as $\epsilon \to 0$). the minus sign is correct, don't know why I said it wasn't (you didn't edit ? )